# Don't know how to do the web-scraping to get this title text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

everyone, I'm trying to learn Python and web-**scraping** with BeautifulSoup4. Taking a shopping web as a practice, I wanna try to get the title text in the picture..but couldn't figure it out.

These are my code so far:

```
source = 'https://ecshweb.pchome.com.tw/search/v3.3/?q=27%E5%90%8B%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95'
response = requests.get(url=source, headers=headers, timeout=15)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

And I wanna get the title text in the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp7E8.png)

Can anyone help??

Comment: You won't get that with `bs4` as the entire site is behind `JavaScript`. Either check if there's an API or explore `selenium`.

Comment: FYI 'scrapping' (and 'scrap') means throwing away like rubbish. The correct term is __scraping__ and __scrape__

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more research, and thanks @baduker for reminding that the website cannot use bs4 to scrape, I realize that the site use AJAX technology.

As a result, I decided to use json and finally get it done. And it revolves around the Network(specifically the XDR thing) in developer mode of browser.